# Shelve Database in Absolute Path

Tags: python, directory, absolute-path, shelve, python-3.6

In Python 3.6 I am trying to but a database called `test.db` in the current user's home directory. Currently, I am getting that directory with `home = os.path.expanduser("~")` (after importing `os`). My problem is that when I run `s = shelve.open(home + "/test")` it creates the file in `/path/to/current/python/file/Users/USERNAME/test.db`. Is there a way to shelve a database by an absolute path, e.g. `/Users/USERNAME/test.db`? Also, can I make it cross platform; Windows would require `shelve.open(home + "\test")` and Mac/Linux would require `shelve.open(home + "/test")`? Thanks.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think there should be a demo script here. Your code should work. I don't know what '/path/to/python/file` is... is it the path to your python script... and you aren't in that directory? But a short script with a few prints would make this more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it cross platform, use `os.path.join()` to join paths

```
import os, shelve
path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), 'test')
shelve.open(path)
```

Comment: If I typed in `test.db`, it would make a file called `test.db.db`.

Comment: On https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html it mentions "file may get suffix added by low-level library". This happened to me on Linux but not Mac. Best not to provide an extension.